# Input com vários valores HTML

Tags: html

Bom, a minha dúvida é a seguinte seria possível eu ter uma input radio com por exemplo os valores:

Portugal
Espanha
França
Brasil,
Alemanha

E a pessoa poder selecionar 2 opções ou seja depois quando passa-se para o PHP tinha 2 values?

Obrigado

Comment: pesquise por `checkbox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode atingir o desejado utilizando o elemento `input type='checkbox'`

Código JS tirado daqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17422484

```js
function teste() {
  var choices = [];
  var els = document.getElementsByName('check');
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i].checked) {
      choices.push(els[i].value);
    }
  }
  alert(choices);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="Brasil" name="check">Brasil
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Portugal" name="check">Portugal
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Espanha" name="check">Espanha
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="França" name="check">França
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Alemanha" name="check">Alemanha
<br/>
<input type="button" value="checar" onclick="teste()">
```

Explicando linha a linha o que o código faz:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Com esse requisito de **NO MINIMO 2 CAMPOS SELECIONADOS E NO MAXIMO 2 CAMPOS SELECIONADOS** você *pode* * fazer assim:

- *Existem outros meios, talvez ate mais simples....*

```js
function teste() {
  var choices = [];
  var els = document.getElementsByName('check');
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i].checked) {
      choices.push(els[i].value);
    }
  }
  if (choices.length <= 1 || choices.length > 2) {
    alert(`necessario 2 campos selecionados`);
  }else{
    alert(`ok, window.submit();`);
  }
  alert(choices);
}
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" value="Brasil" name="check">Brasil
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Portugal" name="check">Portugal
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Espanha" name="check">Espanha
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="França" name="check">França
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Alemanha" name="check">Alemanha
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="checar" onclick="teste()">
```